# PHP mysql sum of column

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS total FORM price_db");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['total'];

echo $sum;
```

When I run this code, nothing is displayed.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Look in the PHP manual on mySQL how to catch and output errors. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: thanks a lot..i should have at least checked that..

Comment: Learn how to handle errors from your database queries, making it easier for you to diagnose problems yourself; and move away from MySQL and and to mySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in your query, it should be `FROM` not `FORM`.